# Ubuntu "Fonts" Lense?

Tags: unity, launcher, fonts, lenses

I use a lot of Ubuntu-Versions with Unity. I have a question about the Lense-Type "**Fonds**"? There are no "**Apps Available for Download**" in the Ubuntu Software Center. Which benefit brings this Lense-Type??

And further - When i want to create a custom launcher, which category-type is to set in the corresponding ***.desktop***-file?
e.g.: a custom launcher for a game - the "**.desktop**-file" contains:

```
...
Categories=Game;
...
```

Here is the category for the correct display in unity dash under type **Games**: "**Game**"
Is it "**Font**" for the type "**Fonts**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site works better if you ask only one question. I can answer your question about menu categories, but not your question about the "Fonts" lens.

No, there is no Font category in the menus. The menus categories and subcategories are defined by a freedesktop standard. You can read it [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html), in the Registed Categories chapter.

You can define it as a new category for your own use in your computer, but you should respect the standard if you are going to package it for others.

About the Font category in Unity, I will post you to the source code line where it is defined in the current trunk (this [file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity-lens-applications/trunk/view/head:/src/daemon.vala), line 235):

```
type_queries.insert ("fonts", "category:Fonts"); // FIXME: wtf?
```

Yes, the comment is real. This looks like a bug, and it's likely that it needs to be removed.

To answer your question: yes, a desktop file with category:Fonts will be displayed in this menu, but it will be non-standard and can cause problems (like appear in Other menus or don't appear) in other DEs, and in Unity in the future if this line is removed.

Comment: THX. Sorry for questioning two things but I thought this two things will match. Maybe I create a new Question for Fonts-use. But now to your answer: On the link i can't find anything about "Font". So this category seems not standard and a Ubuntu-Unity-Specific thing?

Comment: Updated answer.